HP Microsever Gen 8 Ubuntu Server Issues
Really getting to the end of my rope here.
Recently came into the possession of the above model of HP Microserver, the OS of the previous owner had irrevocably corrupted, and with the SD Card reader returning a fault, I cannot use the Intelligent Provisioning service normally available to these HP models in the interrim.
So I tried installing the latest version of Ubuntu Server (24.04 Live AMD64), the installer ran fine burned onto a USB drive, and installed without any issues or problems. When I tried to boot into Ubuntu post-install, it would pull up the menu with OS selection, Ubuntu, Advanced Options, Ubuntu w/ Debian (demands I launch the kernel to configure), Advanced Options.
I select Ubuntu, screen goes black, server restarts.
I have made sure to run the system with AHCI instead of RAID, tinkered with the BIOS settings, everything me, and my Network Manager could think of (IT Apprentice). Nothing, just a constant boot loop.
I am very much a newcomer to Linux, and really wanted to use something different from Windows to try and push the boat out. So I fully admit I'm not 100% on what I am doing. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read How do I ask a good question? And stick to one question instead of asking multiple questions.
